# Java set Data to implemented interface

Tags: interface, implements

How can I fill my implemented interface width the Object it brings width.

```
public class MegaPlayer implements Player{

public MegaPlayer(Player player){
        (?here do I need help?) = player;
```

I like to set the data for the object Player width one step otherwise I have to set any Information separately

Comment: Why do you have implements Player in your constructor body?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense, and neither does your code.  Perhaps a more detailed explanation of what you are doing would help.